# PHP to scrape UL, get the text, store in array, the output again on same page?

Tags: php, web-scraping, preg-match

So after an hours worth of web scouring, I figured I'd ask.  :)  I have found documents that let me grab elements from OTHER pages using DOM or simple XML, but I think that might not be the right way to go. Here is my situation:

I have a page with list elements.

```
<ul id="myId">
    <li><a href="xxx">Unique Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="xxx">Unique Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="xxx">Unique Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="xxx">Unique Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="xxx">Unique Item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="xxx">Unique Item 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="xxx">Unique Item 7</a></li>
</ul>
```

I basically want to scrape these and create an array of ONLY text.  ie `array("Unique Item 1", "Unique Item 2", "Unique Item 3");`

Then simply output that array onto the same page into a form select dropdown (which I have no problem with coding.)

I think a simple preg_match inside a loop may do the trick?

```
preg_match('/^<li">(<a href="[-A-Z0-9_.]+">)([-A-Z0-9 ._]+)<\/a><\/li>$/i', $string, $matches);
```

However, I am unsure of how to tell it to only grab (or loop through) the myID ul.

Any thoughts and help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Theoretically it is possible to use regular expressions as a replacement for a parser, but typically that does not make much sense, since such solutions are not robust in any way. Why do the approaches using a decent DOM parser not satisfy you? Same result, but robust against smaller changes in the scraped markup...

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation that DOMs can scrape the same page they are loaded on since the page isn't exactly loaded while it's working. I am open to using them, but didn't think it would work.

Comment: Sorry, there seems to be some confusion with the terms here. A DOM is an object tree inside a web page. That is nothing you can use to somehow parse. You can use a _DOM parser_ to parse a DOM and extract data from it. There are several solutions for PHP. Your approach would be: request the pages content using `cURL` or maybe even `file_get_contents()` to retrieve the markup, feed that into the parser and then use the output which is an object tree to pick what you are interested in.

Comment: My apologies. I haven't used DOM that much so my terminology is quite skewed with that.  I haven't found ANY documentation though regarding susing either cURL or file_get_contents on the same exact page. All examples I see pull from external documents. Thanks for the feedback, I am going to try to see I can make that work though.

Comment: I am confused, indeed what I referred to is requesting the contents of some remote document to scrape data from it. I cannot see any point in trying to scrape data from some document you are currently creating. You do not have to scrape for that. You already have that data, since you output it! So what is the question here?

Comment: The data that is on the page is raw HTML and is updated via HTML editors. It's not stored anywhere. I am going to do an include file for a contact form at the bottom that needs to see what is hard coded on the page and place in there for the user to select.

Comment: Why would you want to _include_ an html file into the interpretation of a php script? Just load the file content into a string and you have your solution! Then you can parse the string, extract whatever you want. And if really required you can also simply output the string again.

Comment: A general hint: try to think from point of view of someone reading your question. Keep things simple. In this case: _say_ that you have a local file that contains html markup. That you want to parse data from the content of that file.